# Why does the Authorize annotation create a 404 error and not a 401 error?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, authorization

Just curious. I'm trying to make a dynamic error page instead of a different error page for each error in my .NET Core Razor Pages app. I'm adding `[Authorize(Roles="teamleader")]` to the appropriate controller but when I test it, the inspector tells me that it's a `404 - Not Found` error and not a `401 - Unauthorized` error. Anyone know why? Do you need to see some code?

Comment: It's hard to tell with so little information, but my guess here is that it's redirecting you to something like `/Account/Login` and it's *that* URL that 404s.

Comment: check your web browser network tab to see the which request is 404.